# Python Pandas filtering and groupby

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I have this as a csv working in pandas- first ten rows

```
print frame1.head(10)

      alert         Subject    filetype type      country   status
0  33965790    44676 aba     Attachment  doc  RU,RU,RU,RU  deleted
1  33965786    44676 rcrump  Attachment  zip          NaN  deleted
2  33965771            3aba  Attachment  zip          NaN  deleted
3  33965770             NaN  Attachment   js           ,,  deleted
4  33965766             NaN  Attachment   js           ,,  deleted
5  33965761             NaN  Attachment  zip          NaN  deleted
6  33965760             NaN  Attachment  zip          NaN  deleted
7  33965757             NaN  Attachment  zip          NaN  deleted
8  33965751  35200     3aba  Attachment  doc     RU,RU,RU  deleted
9  33965747  35200   INVaba  Attachment  zip          NaN  deleted
```

I need to take the subject column and count for all rows that have 'aba' as a substring.

```
Occurrences of aba- 512
```

or even results like this

```
aba    12
3aba   5
INVaba 2
```

Here is my code -

```
targeted = frame1[frame1['Subject'].str.contains('aba', case=False , na=False)].groupby('Subject')
print (targeted.to_string(header=False))
```

Getting the error - AttributeError: Cannot access callable attribute 'to_string' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

*****Note:  I got this to work earlier for a count of different filetypes, this works -

```
filetype = frame1.groupby('filetype').size()
###clean up the printing
print "Delivered in Email"
print (filetype.to_string(header=False))
```

and gives me -

```
Delivered in Email
Attachment    32647
Header          131
URL            9236
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a full count, just use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) followed by [`count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.count.html).

```
>>> df.Subject.str.contains('aba', case=False, na=False).count()
10
```

Then to get the counts for unique strings which contain `'aba'`, you may access those values found by `contains` and then use [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).

```
>>> df.loc[df.Subject.str.contains('aba', case=False, na=False), 'Subject'].value_counts()

3aba      1
INVaba    1
aba       1
Name: Subject, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0):

for the first output you suggested you can do something like the following:

```
containts_aba = frame1[frame1['Subject'].str.contains('aba', case=False)
print("Occurrences of aba-",len(contains_aba))
```

It creates another dataframe based on your conditions and then the length of that dataframe will be the number of occurrences so then you can just print that.

Answer (score 0):

```
targeted = frame1[frame1['Subject'].str.contains('aba', case=False , na=False)].groupby('Subject').size()
print (targeted.to_string(header=False))
```

Gives

```
3aba      1
INVaba    1
aba       1
```